Add to cart without leaving the page
we have the default add to cart button, that when we click it, it goes to the cart page.
I would like to put a add to cart button on the product card, that doesnt leave the page so the client can still scroll the category and add more products if he wants to.
is it possible to make that button without using the magento files? just front-end html css javascript if possible.
I use the porto magento theme.

Please override the add to cart. phtml for the product page and override list. phtml for category pages, and then put the add to cart button on these files as per your need.

Open the store’s Admin Panel and navigate to STORES → Configuration:
Stores - Configuration

Next, click Checkout under the Sales tab:

Go to the Shopping Cart section and select NO for the After Adding a Product Redirect to Shopping Cart option:

Finally, click the Save Config at the top of the configuration page


Thanks for the quick answer Gohil, i tried myself and it worked, the only problem is that the idea is to have both the add to cart without leaving the page, and the add to cart that goes to the checkout in the same product card.
It worked but now i need a button that goes direct to the checkout hehehe.
Is there a way to do that in code so i can have both buttons?
https://postimg.cc/9RTvqsLH

Then you have to create plugin on  addtocard function to achieve this.

Hey, Gohil Rajesh
Please override the addtocart.phtml for product page and override  list.phtml for category pages , and then put the add to cart button on these files as per you need, Thank You!

but @SanjayJethva here he has enabled "After Adding a Product Redirect to Shopping Cart option", and now he don't want to redirect for some products only, in this case I guess from phtml its not achievalble,  atleast he need to made change in js, anyway thanks for your suggestion brother. I hope he already done this.. hahaha
